# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug when i use AdCash monatisation (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

When I include AdCash library (`compile 'com.adcash:adcash-sdk-lib:2.4.0'`), I have this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\NovaDevelopment\xxx\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\13.0\annotations-13.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [annotations-13.0.jar:org/intellij/lang/annotations/Flow.class]))
```

But without this library, everything works as expected.

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 23
    versionName "2.8"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.eftimoff:android-patternview:1.0.6@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
//    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.9.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
compile('com.smartyads:ad-container:0.4.5') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
compile 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:7.0.0'
compile 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:6.7.0.1@jar'
compile 'com.github.vungle:vungle-android-sdk:5.3.0'
compile 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.2.1'
compile 'com.adcash:adcash-sdk-lib:2.4.0'
implementation files('src/lib/aerserv-sdk.jar')
implementation project(':SDKAndroid')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
```

Any advice?

**UPD**

I resolve this problem, using *.aar library of AdCash instead compile dependency.
Hope, it help anybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem, using `*.aar` library of AdCash instead compile dependency. Hope, it help anybody!

### UPD

In fact, i resolved this problem, by deleting modules in project folder by finder manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PreSchoolFont extends MultiDexApplication {


@Override
public void onCreate() {


    super.onCreate();

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
{
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(PreSchoolFont.this);
}

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:name="com.example.demo.PreSchoolFont "
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup,icon,theme,label">
```

Comment: its application level class not activity

Comment: you need to create new class and after set it in manifest application tag in name attribute and it execute when your application run first execute this class after any activity start